# Deployment Issues With Community License

Tags: deployment, profile, licenses

I'm trying to deploy a community in an org and I'm getting these errors with these profiles...

```
Customer Community Login User   Profile In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Customer Community Login found
Customer Community Plus User    Profile In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Customer Community Plus found
Customer Community User Profile In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Customer Community found
Sikich Community Plus   Profile In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Customer Community Plus found
```

The Target Org has a Community already in place, but how do I set the UserLicense for these to be correct?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details.  Are the source and/or target sandboxes?  Have you checked the license count on the Company Information in Setup?

Comment: Hi going to Source Org to Target Org. Source Org is all good no issues. Target at least has the community in there set up by name. These are community profiles. How are these license set up? I see the target org has the Customer Community Login License with 800 available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you `project-scratch-def.json` have **CustomerCommunityPlus** elements.

Since you included **CustomerCommunityPlus**, it'll add one license in your scratch org.

```java
{
    "orgName": "Org_Name",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["DefaultWorkflowUser", "Communities", "CustomerCommunityPlus", "ForceComPlatform", "FieldAuditTrail"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "networksEnabled": true,
            "chatterEnabled": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```